# What does DISK mean? How to change this param?

Tags: enterprise, orientdb

Right after starting OrientDB (I mean, OrientDB is not under load), using OrientDB-Workbench, I can see that the **DISK** is at 94%. I'm guessing this is not good.

[image]

How does this mean?
How can I configure this?

PS:
In **$ODB_HOME/bin/server.sh**, I have this:

```
MAXHEAP=-Xmx800m
MAXDISKCACHE=-Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=7200
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Changing the configuration to:

```
MAXHEAP=-Xmx8g
MAXDISKCACHE=""
```

won't affect the **DISK**.

[Here](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Performance-Tuning.html#server-and-embedded-settings) recommends the params I had before, but now I see that those are to **plocal** connections. What about **remote**?

Thanks,

Comment: Does `df` also report 94% usage for the filesystem that the database is on?

Comment: Ahah yes. Then DISK really meant disk. Post an answer so I can aprove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dan D. suggested, DISK meant disk space and not some OrientDB setting.